# Which library in C language can I use for toupper and tolower?

Tags: c

I need to use `toupper` and `tolower` but I don't know which library contain this functions.

Please help me!

Comment: man toupper will show it. BTW ctype.h is the header

Answer (score 3):

In almost all environments (including any POSIX environment) both functions are provided by your standard C library - i.e. there is no need to link with a specific library. The manual page for the relevant function will show you what to `#include`; on POSIX the answer is `ctype.h` per the manual page:

```
TOUPPER(3)               BSD Library Functions Manual               TOUPPER(3)

NAME
     toupper, toupper_l -- lower case to upper case letter conversion

LIBRARY
     Standard C Library (libc, -lc)

SYNOPSIS
     #include <ctype.h>

     int
     toupper(int c);
```

Comment: This answer does not provide any meaningful information except a recommondation to look into the manual. It should probably be a comment, not an answer. Downvoting.

Comment: @FUZxxl - Sorry? He asked which library it's in, and I told him - the standard C library! The bit re 'look in the manual page' is about which include file to use - which is not relevant to which library it is in. I've included a snippet from the manual page anyway.

Comment: @FUZxxl this is a straight forward answer to the question. You could better argue the question shouldn't be here in the first place, and indeed, i felt inclined to vote for closing, but couldn't find a matching reason (being "banal" isn't listed as a reason).

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Well, OP is asking for a library. Wouldn't that ...?

Comment: @Olaf yes, sort of ... I mean, he's asking for a function that's part of standard C. It's a poor question, but it should be clarified anyways.